# Modules and classes in Python for a desktop application

Tags: python, class, tkinter, module

This is to be a desktop application for opening multiple small databases and running queries on them. So far I've written some code for opening forms as necessary. Is this a good way to do it? Also - the code shown opens two copies of each form - what am I doing wrong? It's my first attempt at Python and I'm a rudimentary programmer so simple answers would be of most help please. TIA   (Python 3.9.6)

link_1.py

```
from tkinter import Tk
import link_2

root = Tk()

class ClassLink_1:

#if another function in the class is called, the __init__ function is run at start up
    def __init__(self):
        print("in link_1 __init__ instruction")

#the call_function function can be called at start up, or not, and will act accordingly
    def call_function(self):
        print("in call_function")  

#the line below is run at start up whether or not another function in the class is called
    print("in link_1")        

    root.withdraw()             #hides the blank form at start up

#if __name__ == "__main__":
#the line below shows the link_2 form, whether or not the if __name__==__main__ condition is used as its condition
link_2.ClassLink_2(root).__init__(root)
#link_3.ClassLink_3(root).__init__(root)

#the line below runs call_function on start up to print text 
ClassLink_1().call_function()       

root.mainloop()
```

link_2.py

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter import *          #for Toplevel
import link_3
root = Tk()

class ClassLink_2:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.openNewWindow()

    def openNewWindow(self):
        newWindow = Toplevel(root)                          #creates a top level widget with the parent root (first parameter)
        newWindow.title("Title opened from link_1")
        newWindow.geometry("500x500")
        label = Label(newWindow, text ="Opened from link_1").grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.add_button = Button(newWindow, text="in ClassLink_2", command= self.do_add)        
        self.add_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

    def do_add(self):
        print("button pressed")
        link_3.ClassLink_3(root).__init__(root)

    root.withdraw()             #hides the blank form at start up
```

link_3.py

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter import *          #for Toplevel
root = Tk()

class ClassLink_3:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.openNewWindow()

    def openNewWindow(self):
        newWindow = Toplevel(root)                          #creates a top level widget with the parent root (first parameter)
        newWindow.title("Title opened from link_2")
        newWindow.geometry("500x500")
        label = Label(newWindow, text ="Opened from link_2").grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.add_button = Button(newWindow, text="in ClassLink_3", command= self.do_add)        
        self.add_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

    def do_add(self):
        print("button pressed")
#        link_4.ClassLink_4(root).__init__(root)  this file has not yet been made

    root.withdraw()             #hides the blank form at start up
```

Comment: _"Is this a good way to do it?"_ is not an appropriate question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proposed solution, can be expanded as needed. Constructive suggestions for improvement of the structure or code would be appreciated.  TIA.   I've left in the details in case they are of use to anyone.

link_1

```
from tkinter import Tk
import link_2
root = Tk()

class ClassLink_1:
    def __init__(self):
        print("in link_1 __init__ instruction")

    root.withdraw()             #hides the blank form at start up

link_2.ClassLink_2(root).openNewWindow(0)
root.mainloop()
```

link_2

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter import *
import link_3
root = Tk()

class ClassLink_2:
    root.withdraw()             #hides the blank form at start up
    class_var_1 = 0
    inst_var_1 = 0

    def __init__(self, incoming_inst_var_1):  
        pass     

    def openNewWindow(self, inst_var_1_to_open):
        newWindow = Toplevel(root)
        newWindow.title("Title opened from link_1")
        newWindow.geometry("500x500")
        label = Label(newWindow, text ="Opened from link_1").grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.add_button = Button(newWindow, text="in ClassLink_2", command= self.do_add)        
        self.add_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.add_button = Button(newWindow, text="increment class_var_1", command= self.inc_class_var_1)        
        self.add_button.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.inst_var_1 = inst_var_1_to_open

    def do_add(self):
        print("button pressed")
        link_3.ClassLink_3(root).openNewWindow(0)

    def inc_class_var_1(self):
        ClassLink_2.class_var_1 += 2
        self.inst_var_1 += 1
        print("self.class_var_1 = " + (str)(self.class_var_1))
        print("self.inst_var_1 = " + (str)(self.inst_var_1))
```

link_3

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkscrolled
# import link_4 <filename of next form>
root = Tk()

class ClassLink_3:
    class_var_1 = 0
    inst_var_1 = 0

# ------------------------------- START CLASS CONTROLS -----------------------------
    root.withdraw()

    def __init__(self, incoming_inst_var_1):  
        pass     

    def openNewWindow(self, inst_var_1_to_open):
        new_window = Toplevel(root)
        self.widget_factory(new_window)
        self.inst_var_1 = inst_var_1_to_open

    def do_add(self):
        print("button pressed")
#        link_4.ClassLink_4(root).openNewWindow(0)                # <filename of next form>
# ---------------------------------- END CLASS CONTROLS -----------------------------
# -------------------------------------- START CALCS --------------------------------------

    def inc_class_var_1(self):
        ClassLink_3.class_var_1 += 2
        self.inst_var_1 += 1

        print("self.class_var_1 = " + (str)(self.class_var_1))
        print("self.inst_var_1 = " + (str)(self.inst_var_1))
# ---------------------------------------- END CALCS --------------------------------------
# ---------------------------------------- START FACTORY SHOPS-----------------------------------------
    def widget_factory(self, new_window):
        self.shop_window(new_window)
        self.shop_labels(new_window)
        self.shop_buttons(new_window)
        self.shop_menu(new_window)
        self.shop_listbox(new_window)
        self.shop_combobox(new_window)
        self.shop_radiobuttons(new_window)
        self.shop_checkbuttons(new_window)
        self.shop_entries(new_window)
        self.shop_canvas(new_window)
        self.shop_scale(new_window)
        self.shop_scrollbars(new_window)
        self.shop_textbox(new_window)
        self.shop_menu(new_window)
        pass
# ------------------------
    def shop_window(self, new_window):
        new_window.title("Title opened from link_2")
        new_window.geometry("800x900")
     
    def shop_labels(self, new_window): 
        self.label_1 = Label(new_window, text ="Opened from link_2").grid(row=1, column=1)

    def shop_buttons(self, new_window):
        self.button_1 = Button(new_window, text="in ClassLink_3", command= self.do_add)
        self.button_1.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.button_2 = Button(new_window, text="increment class_var_1", command= self.inc_class_var_1)        
        self.button_2.grid(row=5, column=1)

    def shop_listbox(self, new_window):
        data=("one", "two", "three", "four")
        self.listbox_1 = Listbox(new_window, height=5, selectmode='multiple') 
        for num in data:
            self.listbox_1.insert(END,num)
        self.listbox_1.grid(row=7, column=1)

    def shop_combobox(self, new_window):
        data=("one", "two", "three", "four")    
        self.combobox_1 = Combobox(new_window, values=data)  
        self.combobox_1.grid(row=8, column=3)

    def shop_radiobuttons(self, new_window):
        var_1 = IntVar()
        var_1.set(1)
        self.rad_btn_1 = Radiobutton(new_window, text="male",   variable=var_1, value=1)
        self.rad_btn_2 = Radiobutton(new_window, text="female", variable=var_1, value=2) 
        self.rad_btn_1.grid(row=9, column=1)
        self.rad_btn_2.grid(row=9, column=2)

    def shop_checkbuttons(self, new_window):
        var_1 = IntVar()
        var_2 = IntVar()
        self.checkbtn_1 = Checkbutton(new_window, text = "Cricket", variable = var_1)
        self.checkbtn_2 = Checkbutton(new_window, text = "Tennis", variable = var_2)
        self.checkbtn_1.grid(row=10, column=1)
        self.checkbtn_2.grid(row=10, column=2)

    def shop_entries(self, new_window):
        self.entry_1 = Entry(new_window, width = 20)
        self.entry_1.insert(0,'Username')
        self.entry_1.grid(row= 11, column=2)
 
        self.entry_2 = Entry(new_window, width = 15)
        self.entry_2.insert(0,'password')
        self.entry_2.grid(row= 12, column=2)

#might want to place on a frame, see example  https://coderslegacy.com/python/list-of-tkinter-widgets/
    def shop_canvas(self, new_window):
        canvas = Canvas(new_window, bg= 'white', width = 260,height = 260)      #this is the background for the figure
# left and top of figure is from [x from left, y from top] of canvas      right and bottom of figure from [x from left, y from top] of canvas       
        coordinates = 20, 50, 210, 230
        arc = canvas.create_arc(coordinates, start=0, extent=250, fill="blue")          #start is from E, extent is in degrees CCW
        arc = canvas.create_arc(coordinates, start=250, extent=50, fill="red")
        arc = canvas.create_arc(coordinates, start=300, extent=60, fill="yellow")
        canvas.grid(row=2, column=1)
 
    def shop_scale(self, new_window):
        self.scale_1 = Scale(new_window, from_=0, to=10, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.scale_1.grid(row=15, column=2)
        self.scale_2 = Scale(new_window, from_=0, to=10, orient = HORIZONTAL)
        self.scale_2.grid(row=15, column=3)

    def shop_scrollbars(self, new_window):
        self.scroll_vert = Scrollbar(new_window) 
        self.scroll_vert.grid(row=19, column=3)

        self.listbox_3 = Listbox(new_window, yscrollcommand = self.scroll_vert.set )  
        for line in range(1, 100): 
            self.listbox_3.insert(END, "Number " + str(line)) 
        self.listbox_3.grid(row=19 , column=2)    

        self.scroll_vert.config(command = self.listbox_3.yview) 

    def shop_textbox(self, new_window):
    #make a frame with parent new_window
        self.frame_textbox_1 = Frame(new_window)
        self.frame_textbox_1.grid(row=1, column=5)

    #make the textbox with parent frame
        self.textbox_1 = Text(self.frame_textbox_1)
        self.textbox_1.config(wrap=NONE, width=15, height=8)     #width, height are characters x rows  permitted wrap values should be WORD CHAR, or NONE

    #make the X scrollbar with parent frame
        self.scroll_text_horiz = Scrollbar(self.frame_textbox_1, orient="horizontal") 
        self.scroll_text_horiz.config(command = self.textbox_1.xview)
    #make the Y scrollbar with parent frame
        self.scroll_text_vert = Scrollbar(self.frame_textbox_1, orient="vertical") 
        self.scroll_text_vert.config(command = self.textbox_1.yview) 

    #pack the scrollbars before the texbox to allow them to fill the frame width and height 
        self.scroll_text_horiz.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)             
        self.scroll_text_vert.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.textbox_1.pack(fill="y")           

    #connect the scrollbars to the textbox
        self.textbox_1["xscrollcommand"] = self.scroll_text_horiz.set
        self.textbox_1["yscrollcommand"] = self.scroll_text_vert.set

        message = "the quick brown fox"
        self.textbox_1.insert(1.1, message)

# ----------------------------------------------

    def shop_menu(self, new_window): 
        print("in shop menu1")       
        menubar = Menu(new_window) 
        print("in shop_menu2")  

        file = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)  
        file.add_command(label="New")  
        file.add_command(label="Open")  
        file.add_command(label="Save")  
        file.add_command(label="Save as...")  
        file.add_command(label="Close")  
        file.add_separator()  
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=new_window.quit)  
        
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)  
        edit = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)  
        edit.add_command(label="Undo")  
        
        edit.add_separator()  
        
        edit.add_command(label="Cut")  
        edit.add_command(label="Copy")  
        edit.add_command(label="Paste")  
        edit.add_command(label="Delete")  
        edit.add_command(label="Select All")  
        
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit)  
        help = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)  
        help.add_command(label="About")  
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help)  
        
        new_window.config(menu=menubar)
        print("in shop menu3") 

# --------------------------------------- END FACTORY SHOPS---------------------------------------
```